# Intersection of equivalence relations is an equivalence relation

Tags: equivalence-relations, solution-verification

Theorem:

> Given a collection $S$ of equivalence relations on a set $X:=\left\{x_{1},...,x_{n}\right\}$, then the intersection of elements in $S$ is also an equivalence relation.

Proof (my try):

The intersection is not empty since all of the equivalence relations should be reflexive , in other words the identity relation $Id_X$  is contained in all of the elements in $S$, hence the least intersection that they can have is $Id_x$ which is itself an equivalence relation, but if it's not the intersection then there exist **at least** another ordered pair $\left(x_{i},x_{j}\right)$ in $Id_X$, but symmetry implies $\left(x_{j},x_{i}\right)$ $\left(1\le i<j\le n\right)$ is also  contained in $Id_X$, on the hand the other case would be that these ordered pairs by transitivity add another ordered pair, in all of these cases the relation is an equivalence.

Is my proof right?

Have someone any better proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "symmetry implies..."

Symmetry of what then?

And also you seem to be saying that $(x_j,x_i)\in\mathsf{Id}_X$ in spite of $i\neq j$.

I cannot recognize your "proof" as a correct proof.

---

Let $X$ be a set and let $\mathcal S$ denote the collection of equivalence relations on $X$.

(It is not necessary to demand that $X$ is finite)

Defining $E:=\bigcap\mathcal S$ it must be proved the $E$ is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

- reflexivity.

*Every* element of $\mathcal S$ is reflexive so that $(x,x)\in E$ for arbitrary $x\in X$.

- symmetry.

Let $(a,b)\in E$ or equivalently $(a,b)\in R$ for every $R\in\mathcal S$. Then also $(b,a)\in R$ for every $R\in\mathcal S$ because every $R\in\mathcal S$ is symmetric. This justifies the conclusion that $(b,a)\in E$.

- transitivity.

Let $(a,b)\in E$ and $(b,a)\in E$ or equivalently...

Try to do the rest of this yourself, inspired by the handling of symmetry above.

Comment: Thanks for the consideration ,I said $i\neq j$, because if $i\neq j$ then we have an ordered pair which is already contained in $\mathsf{Id}_X$ (although if I remove the condition the result still follows), Also the reason why I used $ \mathsf{Id}_X$ is that to show the intersection of elements in the collection is at least $\mathsf{Id}_X$, and should not you say $E:=\bigcap S$ instead of $E:=\bigcap\mathcal S$?

Comment: Well, whatever. I am sure that what you wrote will not be accepted as a correct proof. Also observe that José (the other answerer) does not understand it.

Comment: yes you are totally right, mine is not good

Comment: My notation is indeed not completely in accordance with yours. I used $\mathcal S$ for your $S$, and I denoted elements of $\mathcal S$ by $S$. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: the notations are good but you said $\color{red}{S}\in\color{blue}{\mathcal S}$, so $S$ is an arbitrary element in $\mathcal S$ so $E$ should be the intersection of  elements in $\mathcal S$, which means $E:=\bigcap\color{red}{S}$ instead of $E:=\bigcap\color{blue}{\mathcal S}$, because you are intersecting the **elements** in  $\mathcal S$ **not** $\mathcal S$ itself

Comment: @user715522 Indeed I caused some confusion by using $S$ as element of $\mathcal S$ while the term $S$ was used in the question already (see former comments). I repaired by an edit and changed $S$ into $R$.

Comment: Should not it be $E:=\bigcap R$? because you are intersecting all equivalence relations $R$ in $\mathcal S$ **not** $\mathcal S$ itself, because if $E:=\bigcap\mathcal S$ then you are intersecting all of such **collections**

Comment: @user715522 No. If $\mathcal S$ is a collection of relations then by definition $(x,y)\in\bigcap\mathcal S\iff (x,y)\in R\text{ for every }R\in\mathcal S$. That is based on the concept of operation $\bigcap$ on sets. We could also write $\bigcap\mathcal S:=\bigcap_{R\in\mathcal S}R$.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say whether is right or wrong, since I don't understand what you wrote, other than the assertion that the intersection must contain $\operatorname{Id}_X$ and therefore it must be reflexive (which is correct, by the way).

Let $I$ be the intersection. Then $I$ is symmetric because if $x\mathrel Iy$, then $(x,y)$ belongs to every element of $S$. But every element of $S$ is symmetric and therefore $(y,x)$ also belongs to every element of $S$. In other words, $y\mathrel Ix$.

And $I$ is transitive to. If $x\mathrel Iy$ and $y\mathrel Iz$, then both pairs $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$ belong to each element of $S$. Sense every element of $S$ is transitive, $(x,z)$ also belongs to every element of $S$. So, $x\mathrel Iz$.

Comment: nice, that is exactly what I was trying to say but your words are of course better than mine, the intersection of all elements in $S$ is reflexive by definition of an equivalence relation and checking that the intersection is symmetric and transitive is what should be proved